# Room android LiveData observe call only 2 times

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I have a problem using LiveData in Room library android.

I have a Fragment where there is a `RecyclerView` and to populate use `LiveData` with `Observer`

```
mDB.user().getUsers().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<UserModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<UserModel> userModels) {
            updateUI(userModels);
        }
});
```

If I click on ADD button, call a `startActivity`, open a new Activity with my form, compile all fields and `@INSERT` a new item on DB

```
AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
        mDB.user().addUser("NAME");
        finish();
});
```

When finish the current Activity, show again previous Fragment and automatically should be call the `onChanged`. The `observe` is called only for 2 times, than, if I click on ADD button (for 3th time) and come back to the fragment, never call and never refresh my list.
I don't know why.

I tried with `observeForever` without results.

I see that in debug, never called `removeObserver`, so the observer is active.

These are my dependencies

```
def room_version = "2.2.5"
def lifecycle_version = "2.3.0-alpha01"

// Room database
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
// ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
// LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"
```

Comment: In which method of your Fragment are you calling LiveData.observe()?

Comment: in onCreateView, but I have tried in onCreate too

Comment: So for the first two inserts, it updates the UI fine but on the third onwards, it doesn't?

Comment: yes, exactly. 

1 - click ADD...compile, call INSERT, finish() -> in fragment the observer update the UI

2 - click ADD...compile, call INSERT, finish() -> in fragment the observer update the UI

3 - click ADD...compile, call INSERT, finish() -> in fragment the observer DOESN'T update the UI

Comment: You may also wanna share the onClick() method for add button and updateUI() method.

Comment: when click on button ADD, I call this

     `AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
        mDB.user().addUser("NAME");
        finish();
     });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210105/discussion-between-shahood-ul-hassan-and-carlos).

Answer (score 0):

You should call `observe()` from `onResume()` of `UsersFragment`, instead of `onCreateView()` because for adding a new user, you are switching to a new Activity which pauses the current activity and the fragments attached to it instead of destroying the views of the fragments. So, when you come back to the current activity, `onCreateView()` of `UsersFragment` never gets called, `onResume()` is called however.

I would, however, suggest you to implement a proper `ViewModel`, `Repository` pattern for communicating with `Room` database.

Comment: `observe()` cannot call in `onResume()` because this I need to call only 1 time in `onCreateView()`. If call in `onResume()`, this will call every time that I come back from activity.
The problem was that in my BaseFragment and my BaseActvity, in `onDestroy()` set Room `instance = null`.
Removing this, now It's all ok.

Comment: You can do it like `if (!mDB.user().getUsers().hasObservers()) {// Attach observer}`.

Comment: how about using `viewLifecycleOwner` as lifecycle owner?